# I am looking for a modern and thorough exposition for presentations of groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, big-list, group-presentation

Conider the following abstract description for the Quaternion group:

$$\langle x,y\mid x^{4}=1,x^{2}=y^{2},y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}\rangle$$

This description is called a **presentation** of the Quaternion group via generators and relations.

I am looking for a modern and thorough exposition for presentations of groups because I think it is a fascinating area about which I would like to know more. Are there any books or comprehensive online sources that you could recommend?

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: Dear Moritz, almost every book on group theory has a chapter on presentation of groups, free groups, free products of groups and so on :) Perhaps you like my [lecture notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_54_groups.pdf), in particular chapter $4$ and its references.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: Thank you for your kind response. I know that books about group theory have often small chapters (in general about 10 pages long)  about this topic or treat it as a secondary subject. I was looking more for a "monograph" about presentations - if such a thing exists. I also found lecture notes from a course by Derek Holt about the theme but they were taken by a student and were full of errors. So, my question is about a good _personal_ recommendation that someone could give me: comprehensive, modern and - if possible - error free. A book is good, an online source even better.

Comment: Have you looked at *Presentation of groups* by Johnson, or any book on/titled Combinatorial group theory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combinatorial group theory books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974201/combinatorial-group-theory-books)

Comment: While I voted to close as duplicate it is worth pointing out that combinatorial group theory is very influenced nowadays by geometric group theory, so it is also worth looking into that. Check out [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3858/introductory-text-on-geometric-group-theory) for that

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: Thank you for the link to your lecture notes!! I will enjoy studying them.

Comment: @Paul Plummer: No, I did not know "Combinatorial group theory" but I have already ordered it. It seems a little dated but over 400 pages on the other hand  seems promising. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer occurs in the comments above. I summarize

- "Combinatorial Group Theory: Presentations of Groups in Terms of
  Generators and Relations" by W. Magnus and others, 444 pages, ISBN
  0486438309, 2004-reprint of 1976-edition
- "Presentations of Groups,
  2ed" by D.L. Johnson, 232 pages, ISBN 0521585422, 2008-reprint of
  1997-edition
- "Topics in the theory of group presentations" by D. L.
  Johnson, 311 pages, ISBN 9780521231084, 2008-reprint of 1980-edition